# Availability Group - how much data was lost after forced failover

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, clustering, high-availability, failover

Let's consider a SQL Server AlwaysOn cluster with two nodes in asynchronous replication.
Is there any way to calculate how much data was lost after forced failover?

I mean in terms of time, to be able to know "I lost 1 hour of data or 1 minute".
I have considered checking LSNs but I don't know how to translate them into datetime.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Go to SSMS
2. Object Explorer
3. Expand `Always On High Availability`
4. Expand `Availability Groups`
5. Right click your AG
6. Select `Show Dashboard`

In the dashboard, above the list of AG databases and their status, there is `Add/Remove Columns` button

Pick `Estimated Data Loss (time)` and add this column to dashboard
You will be able to see the estimated data loss time for each DB

You can check this dashboard right before you are going to do forced failover, to get the idea of how much data can be lost

[image: AG Estimated Data Loss]

Answer (score 4):

You can create a "canary" table which contains only one row with one datetime column and update this column on scheduled basis (every minute, for example). This way you can check this table on secondary replica (even when primary one is already unavailable) and be sure that it is synchronized at least till this timestamp (actully you may lose less data because some transactions may be synced after the last "canary" table update job was executed).

Comment: Would you need to have the same table in each database participating in the AG, as some would possibly be further behind than others due to transaction volume?

Comment: @BCM yes, you would need to create the table in each database